# W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease Unable to find

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile, debian-jessie

I found [here](https://bitbucket.org/jason_c_kwan/orthomcl_docker/overview) the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM appcontainers/mysql:debian
MAINTAINER Jason C. Kwan "jason.kwan@wisc.edu"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget cpanminus build-essential libmysqlclient-dev python
RUN wget http://www.micans.org/mcl/src/mcl-latest.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf mcl-latest.tar.gz
RUN cd mcl-* && ./configure && make && make install
RUN wget http://orthomcl.org/common/downloads/software/v2.0/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz
RUN cpanm DBI DBD::mysql
RUN mkdir diamond && cd diamond && wget http://github.com/bbuchfink/diamond/releases/download/v0.9.14/diamond-linux64.tar.gz && tar xvf diamond-linux64.tar.gz
RUN rm *.tar.gz

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/
COPY run_orthomcl.py /bin/
ENV PATH="/diamond:/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/bin:${PATH}"
```

During the building stage I got the below error:

```
$ docker build -t orthomcl_docker . 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  95.23kB
Step 1/15 : FROM appcontainers/mysql:debian
debian: Pulling from appcontainers/mysql
e80d11fe101a: Pull complete 
125a38e742bc: Pull complete 
8900111cfb5b: Pull complete 
8d736c21b481: Pull complete 
3d0796a1857b: Pull complete 
158bbfe64bb1: Pull complete 
3e3a4a0e9680: Pull complete 
ed389ac8eaad: Pull complete 
8c74473c64df: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:df4892c59ffea2dee490c140fcc4a6b0e0c8f5b030d246e9a020d0713c1d986a
Status: Downloaded newer image for appcontainers/mysql:debian
 ---> 2f3334384d52
Step 2/15 : MAINTAINER Jason C. Kwan "jason.kwan@wisc.edu"
 ---> Running in 98824b90f29f
Removing intermediate container 98824b90f29f
 ---> 466abf48a731
Step 3/15 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 330f1f153798
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [7340 B]
Get:3 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2420 B]
Get:4 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [829 kB]
Get:6 http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 12s (838 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: This is where I grumble about Docker's error messages being awful. It's *actually* running `/bin/sh -c 'apt-get update'` (which is exactly what it should be running!), but it's saying in the message that it's running `/bin/sh -c apt-get update` (which has an obvious bug in that it doesn't actually pass the argument `update` to `apt-get`, but instead discards that argument as an unused value for `$0`). So we see the title and think it's the obvious bug, where it's really just bad logging.

Comment: BTW, insofar as your *real* error is related to the warning `W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`, it might make sense to focus the question around it. The non-zero exit code follows directly from the ability to download the indexes, which follows directly from that `sources.list` file being invalid.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue recently and I find this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/508948).
Some quick snippet from the solution:

```
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

However in my case I have `.dockerfile` working with `install.sh`, the solution above give me a new error "*Release file expired* and need to add this [extra line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/510189):

```
RUN echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until
```